# replace string only if condition in other column is met

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements, gsub

i have a data frame

```
test<-data.frame(A=c("aa","be","cg","dh"),B=c("i","i","i","i"))

   A   B
1 aa  i
2 be  i
3 cg  i
4 dh  i
```

I want to replace `i` in column `B` with `yes` ONLY if in column `B` the string `e` is found.

So in the end, it should look like this

```
  A   B
1 aa   i
2 be yes
3 cg   i
4 dh   i
```

I have tried

```
test[(grep("e", test$A)),] <- as.data.frame(lapply(test, gsub, pattern=      "i", replacement="yes", test$B))
```

while both parts work seperately, the combination does not give me the output i want

Comment: What you have _tried_ is unreadable. Please provide an easier to use code.

Comment: This is quite basic subsetting and assignment. Have a read of `help("[")`. The solution is much simpler than what you have. For example, the right hand side can be replaced by "yes".

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to go about this. A nifty way to do this in data.table:

```
test<-data.frame(A=c("aa","be","cg","dh"),B=c("i","i","i","i"))
library(data.table)
test = as.data.table(test)
test[grepl("e",A),B := "yes"]
```

or in dplyr:

```
test<-data.frame(A=c("aa","be","cg","dh"),B=c("i","i","i","i"))
library(dplyr)
test = tbl_df(test)
test %>% mutate(B = ifelse(grepl("e",A),"yes",B))
```

Comment: Fyi, data.table also offers `A %like% "e"` instead of `grepl`.

Answer (score 3):

The `ifelse` function comes in handy here:

```
test$B <- ifelse(grepl("e", test$A), gsub("i", "yes", test$B), test$B)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your strings are strings and not factors:

```
test<-data.frame(A=c("aa","be","cg","dh"),B=c("i","i","i","i"),
    stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Then this will work:

```
test[grep("e", test$A),]$B =
    gsub(pattern= "i", replacement="yes", test[grep("e", test$A),]$B);
```

Better still is to switch from `data.frame` to `data.table`, and then it's just this:

```
test[grepl("e", A), B := gsub("i", "yes", B)];
```

Note: this assumes that you want to replace "i" in B with "yes", "ii" with "yesyes", "iai" with "yesayes", etc... If instead you just want to set the value of B to "yes" whenever A has an "e", then this:

```
test[grepl("e", A), B := "yes"];
```

Or if you want to set the value of B to "yes" whenever B is "i" and A has an "e", then this:

```
test[B=="i" & grepl("e", A), B := "yes"];
```